# The integral $\int_0^{\frac{1}{2}}\frac{x^{k-1}}{1-x^{2^k}}dx$ and how simplify the Pochhmammer symbol in related series

Tags: sequences-and-series, definite-integrals, hypergeometric-function, beta-function, pochhammer-symbol

Inspired in the shape of useful integrals to **compute** $\pi$ (see *), I've consider for each integer $k\geq 1$ $$\int_0^{\frac{1}{2}}\frac{x^{k-1}}{1-x^{2^k}}dx=\int_0^{\frac{1}{2}}x^{k-1}\sum_{n=0}^\infty \left( x^{2^k} \right)^n dx=\frac{1}{2^k}\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{1}{2^{n2^k}(n2^k+k)},$$
and as you see in this series doesn't appear any **Pochhmammer symbol.**
Let the change of variable $u=x^{2^k}$ then $\log x=2^{-k}\log u$ and $\frac{dx}{x}=2^{-k}\frac{du}{u}$, thus we can write $$\frac{x^{k-1}}{1-x^{2^k}}dx=\frac{x^{k-1}}{1-u}2^{-k}\frac{du}{u}.$$
Define $\text{factor}:=x^k$ then $\log(\text{factor})=k2^{-k}\log u$ (by substitution of $\log x=2^{-k}\log u$ ) thus by exponentiation $\text{factor}:=u^{\frac{k}{2^k}}$ and we can write our integral as 
$$\int_0^{\frac{1}{2}}\frac{x^{k-1}}{1-x^{2^k}}dx=\frac{1}{2^k}\int_0^{\frac{1}{2^{2^k}}}\frac{u^{-1+\frac{k}{2^k}}}{1-u}du$$
for $k\geq 1$, since if $x=\frac{1}{2}$ the corresponding upper limit in previous integral is computed as was written.

I would like to know and learn more computations involving special functions and numbers.

> **Question.** It's possible to prove that previous integral, which can be written in terms of particular values of the **incomplete Beta function** or the **hypergeometric function**, is equals to previous computed series when you simplify the corresponding Pochhmmmer symbols that appear in the expansion series of $B(z;a,b)$ or $_2F_1(a,b;c,z)$? **Thanks in advance.**

I say only an exercise: show your simplifications with the Beta or the hypergeometric, one of them. I will accept the best answer.

*The reference is a divulgative paper in spanish, the referenced equation is **the first integral after (29) in page 171**, I don't know who proved it, neither if my integral was known in the literature; **Guillera,** [Historia de las fórmulas y algoritmos para $\pi$, La Gaceta de la RSME Vol. 10 No. 1 (2007)](http://gaceta.rsme.es/abrir.php?id=611).

Comment: My code for the [Wolfram Alpha online calculator](https://www.wolframalpha.com/) is integrate (x^(k-1))/(1-x^(2^k)) dx

Comment: In the second integral you forgot the exponents $n$, it should be
$$\int_0^{\frac{1}{2}}x^{k-1}\sum_{n=0}^\infty \left( x^{2^k} \right)^{n} dx$$

Comment: Was **fixed** previous typo. Very thanks much @gammatester , and all users.